# Only adding non-duplicate values to PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, sql-insert, knex.js

I'm wondering what the best practice would be for avoiding duplication inside of a PostgreSQL database table. The rows in the table are equivalent to entries from a 3rd party API which is called several times throughout the day.

I am only adding entries that are not duplicates from the JSON response. The JSON response can be upwards of 500 objects in the database, lets say:

```
[{
  "unique_id": 1234,
  "name": "A",
  "wins": 1
},
{
  "unique_id": 1235
  "name": "B",
  "wins": 1
}, 
... 
];
```

**The issue is that the data from the API may be data I've already stored away in the database and when I query the 3rd party endpoint again, I don't want to have the data that has already been inserted added again - only the unique objects in the result.**

And I'm aware how I could check if one individual object exists as a row, but when I have upwards of 500 in the 3rd party response and only 50 of them will be unique, what would be the reasonable check for this in one database transaction?

I was tempted to go so far as to `SELECT * FROM table_name`, add those results to the json response, then remove duplicates that way, but that seems like an awful lot of overhead processing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to proceed is to declare a unique constraint (or a unique index, or a primary key) that references the relevant columns in the table. You can the use the `on conflict do nothing` clause in your `insert` queries:

Example:

```
create table mytable(unique_id int, name text, wins int);
create unique index myidx on mytable(unique_id, name, wins);

insert into mytable (unique_id, name, wins) 
values(1234, 'A', 1)
on conflict(unique_id, name, wins) do nothing;
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a [UNIQUE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) constraint on the column that needs to be unique, and then insert with [ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) (or `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`, if you didn't know that was an option, but is what you'd actually want to do).